# WPF DatePicker to Display only available Dates

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have a DatePicker so the user can select dates.

I want that the user to select only the available Date.
and the availabe dates are stored in a `List`

So far I have this:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker"
  SelectedDate="{Binding SearchEngineCompassLogView.DateSearch,
      Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  DataContext="{StaticResource CompassLogView}">
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: Wouldn't using of a date picker be confusing in this case. Can't you go with simple dropdown list/combo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BlackoutDates` property but in this solution you must specified `DisplayDateStart` and `DisplayDateEnd`.

The `BlackoutDates` is a collection of dates that are not available for selection ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.blackoutdates.aspx)).

Example:

```
 <DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" 
                    Loaded="datePicker_Loaded"
                    DisplayDateStart="2000/01/01"
                    DisplayDateEnd="2050/01/01"
                    />
```

Loaded event handler:

```
private void datePicker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DatePicker picker = sender as DatePicker;

    if (picker.DisplayDateStart == null || picker.DisplayDateEnd == null) return;

    picker.BlackoutDates.Clear();

    DateTime start = picker.DisplayDateStart.Value;
    DateTime end = picker.DisplayDateEnd.Value;

    while (start <= end)
    {
        if (!availableDates.Contains(start))
        {
            picker.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(start, start));
        }
        start = start.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Collection with available dates:

```
List<DateTime> availableDates = new List<DateTime> 
{
    new DateTime(2013, 03, 01),
    new DateTime(2013, 03, 02),
    new DateTime(2013, 03, 03),
    new DateTime(2013, 03, 31),
    new DateTime(2013, 02, 01),
    new DateTime(2013, 02, 02),
    new DateTime(2013, 05, 01),
    new DateTime(2013, 05, 02)
};
```